# Dafny function returning a set of points

Tags: dafny

Let `Rectangle` and `Pair` be Dafny datatypes that are defined as follows :

```
datatype Rectangle = rect(pos: Pair, width: int, height: int)
datatype Pair = pair(x: int, y: int)
```

One mathematical abstraction/representation for this rectangle, which I would like to code in Dafny, is the set of all points (i,j) that this rectangle contains. For example the rectangle rect(pos:(5,5), width=2, height=3) represents the set of points : {(5,5), (6,5), (7,5), (5,6), (6,6), (7,6)}

Let `abs` be a *function method* (one line method) that returns this abstraction in the form of a `set<Pair>`, given a variable of type `Rectangle`

```
function method abs(rect: Rectangle): set<Pair>
{
    //..?
}
```

Does anyone know how to express this set in one line in Dafny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to swap the meaning of height and width that I'd expect, but here's a solution:

```
function method abs(rect: Rectangle): set<Pair>
{
    set x:int, y:int | 0 <= x - rect.pos.x < rect.height &&
                       0 <= y - rect.pos.y < rect.width :: pair(x, y)
}
```

The following lemma demonstrates that the solution satisfies your test case:

```
lemma lemma_Test()
{
    var r := rect(pair(5, 5), 2, 3);
    var s := abs(r);
    assert s == {pair(5,5), pair(6,5), pair(7,5), pair(5,6),
                 pair(6,6), pair(7,6)};
}
```